# is it quicker to refer to a cell or call a function in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I need to call a function, e.g., today() for a formula in many rows of many columns (block). Will my sheet update quicker if I call today() in each cell of the block, or if I replace the call by a reference to another cell where today() is called (e.g., refer to $A$1, where A1 has =today() in it)? Or does it make no difference?

Answer (score 0):

I would go for the second scenario: =today() in one cell and then reference that cell. I didn't test but it surely should be faster.

Comment: You would think, unless a cell is recalculated each time it is referenced, in which case it will work out nearly the same or slightly longer.